# Mobile Safari - viewport device-height not working as expected

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari, viewport

I have a web app that I'm trying to run on an iPad 3.  When I pull it up, the app is allowing vertical scroll when it shouldn't be.  I've gone through the same process with other web apps without any issues, and am not sure what I am missing this time around.

Inside head element of my html, I have the following meta tags:

```
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

In my CSS:

```
    html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
```

Trying to debug this issue in weinre and discovered that the document width and height are somehow equal, when height show be much smaller (in landscape).

```
    $(document).width();  // returns 1024
    $(document).height(); // returns 1024
```

Searching around SO, other answers have been to supply a viewport meta tag, which I'm already doing.  Can someone point me to a solution here?

Comment: have you tried `overflow:hidden!important;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using too many properties of `viewport` that might conflict with each other. [Apple suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP4000) to set few of them or one and test in isolation as others are automatically inferred.

[Bootstrap in its basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) recommends to set only `width` and `initial-scale`.

I would be [very careful with `maximum-scale` or anything restricting user's zooming](http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-use-maximum-scale/) as it forces the user into uncomfortably small (or large) text.

Comment: I would agree about maximum-scale usually, but it is necessary for what I'm trying to accomplish. The web app is supposed to look and behave like a interactive vehicle infotainment system for a demo. Zooming in would be unexpected and jarring for those we're demonstrating to.

Comment: Why not leaving the user to decide about zooming? If they don't like it they can always zoom back.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for some reason this worked when I removed "height=device-height" from the viewport meta tag.  Not sure why since I literally just copy and pasted this tag from another app that worked just fine.  Working viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```